# How to make an a-tag disappear by using js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking at thousands of tutorials to make the a-tag dissappear and reappear for my Login form but not one worked for me. Even if I copy and pasted it it wouldn't work. Here's my code

```
    <form>
        <input type="submit" name="btnadd" value="Login" onsubmit="hide()">
        <a style="color: red;" id="notfound">User not found!</a>
    </form>

</div>
<script>
    var hide = function() {
        var x = document.getElementById("notfound");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please help me to make this work.

Comment: `onsubmit` will submit your page, try returning false from your hide function to prevent the default action of the submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 problems.

1. When a form gets submitted, the default actions to reload current page, so you need to prevent that.
2. onsubmit is part of the form, not the button.

Below is a working example.

ps.  Using onsubmit, onclick etc directly on elements is not the modern way, have a look a addEventListener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener for better DOM event handling.

ps.  If you run the snippet, you might notice when you click the button again, the a link shows belows, that's because an anchor tag is default inline, and not block.  so to stop this you could change it to inline.

```js
var hide = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("notfound");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<div>Login Page.</div>

<form onsubmit="return hide();">
  <input type="submit" name="btnadd" value="Login">
  <a style="color: red;" id="notfound">User not found!</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were actually very close, the styling should just be:

`x.style.visibility = 'hidden'`

That is if the effect your going for is for it to be completely invisible.

Answer (score 0):

OnSubmit will not get it done. use onClick="myFunction();".
document.getElementById("notfound").style.visibility = "hidden";

Comment: Submit works fine but I have to define it in the form tag

Comment: yeah. that it. inside a <form> or prevent that event to proceed further.